# Count multiple appearances in DISTINCT statement with two parameters?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I am trying to filter (or count) companies with multiple contact persons from a table containing a company_id and a person_id. Currently I just do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_id,person_id FROM mytable GROUP BY company_id ORDER BY company_id
```

as well as

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_id FROM mytable
```

The first query returns a couple of rows more. Hence it is obvious that there are companies with multiple contact persons. From the different row count between the two queries I can even tell how many of them. Though I´d like to know how I can select exactly those companies that have more than one person_id assigned.

Thx in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT company_id, COUNT(DISTINCT person_id)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) > 1
```

Comment: and usually I do `ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) DESC`.

Comment: wow, that was quick. "You can accept the answer in 2 minutes". That never happened to me before. Not knowing about HAVING prevented rookie one from finding the obviously obvious. Thx eumiro and Benoit!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   company_id
FROM
   mytable
GROUP BY
   company_id
HAVING
   COUNT(person_id) > 1
ORDER BY
   company_id
```